# Database Design mySQL one or many table(s) and use innodb or myisam for performance

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, innodb, myisam

I will allow users to upload following files - PDF/Videos/Photos. All files uploaded by the user are shown on a profile page. All uploaded files can be searched by name or tags and file type.

At moment i will store all files in **one** mySQL table, **myisam** engine used for fulltext and tag searching and also **faster** to select data.

Say if their were over 10+ million records stored in this one table,  the search would be eventually get slow. i am thinking of breaking the **single table into three separate tables** e.g a table for pdf/photos/videos in this case if the users want to search all file type, i do union all search. would this be a better approach ?

the drawback would be if I add a new file type at later stage i would have to create a new table , for example allow users to upload zip files.

Would **innodb** be a better choice if multiple users are uploading at same time, innodb has row locking would be suited for this, correct?

thanks, :)

edit: i store file paths in the db tables not the actual file  itself.

Comment: you store the files also in the table?

Comment: @rene oops,  i store file paths in the table not the actual file itself. sorry about that,

Comment: Do you really need fulltext search for name/tag search?

Comment: @Nanne fulltext might not be needed in this case, i could just use 'LIKE' .

Answer (score 0):

Keep the file information in one table say document with filename, path, size, uploader, descriptions and maintain another table for tags since each document can have more than one tag. Also you need to store one tag per row in the tags file.

This will enable you do fancy things like tag clouds, tag links on the left hand side of this Stack Overflow page

You may also want to use InnoDB which provide foreign key support, and better performance in the later versions of MySQL 5.1.x and higher. From 5.6 there may be full text indexing too